# PHP parse Ping command output with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I would like to parse the output of the ping command in Linux.
My current code is working fine, the only problem is, that it only parse the first result.
I would like to change it to parse every line.

The red marked lines should also be parsed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVqzV.png
What do I have to change to do that?

That's my current regular expression:
https://regex101.com/r/uH0XwP/1

That's the current PHP code:

```
$re = '/^PING\b[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)\s([^.]*)\..*?^(\d+\sbytes).*?icmp_seq=(\d+).*?ttl=(\d+).*?time=(.*?ms).*?(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted.*?(\d+)\sreceived.*?(\d+%)\spacket\sloss.*?time\s(\d+ms).*?=\s([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/(.*?)\sms/ims';
$str = 'PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=0.816 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=0.883 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=0.743 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=0.613 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3033ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.613/0.763/0.883/0.105 ms
';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Thank a lot.
With best regards

Comment: This probably isn’t what you want, but I’d break this up into per-line rules, split the ping results into lines and loop over them performing if `preg_match` tests on each. It feels less eloquent, but it is way easier to debug and reason about. You can also log single lines that don’t match your patterns to find edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is structured like that, you might make use of the `\G` anchor

```
(?:^PING\b[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)\s([^.]*)\..*|\G(?!^))\R^(\d+\sbytes).*?icmp_seq=(\d+).*?ttl=(\d+).*?time=(.*?ms).*(?:\s+---.*\R(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted.*?(\d+)\sreceived.*?(\d+%)\spacket\sloss.*?time\s(\d+ms)\R.*=\s([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/(.*?)\sms)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WClUY/1)

In your pattern there are multiple occurrences of `.*?` that might also be replaced by a more specific part like spaces or digits with an optional decimal part

```
(?:^PING\b[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)\s([^.]*)\.|\G(?!^))\R(\d+\sbytes).*?icmp_seq=(\d+)\h+ttl=(\d+).*?time=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+ms).*(?:\s+---.*\R(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted.*?(\d+)\sreceived,\h*(\d+%)\spacket\sloss,\h+time\s(\d+ms)\R.*=\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\sms)?
```

Then using preg_match_all the values are in group 3 - group 6

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/kenjU)

Another option is to match the repeating data in between in a capture group, and process those lines separately. In the next pattern, capture group 3 contains the repeating lines that you could parse separately in a second step.

```
^PING\b[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)\s([^.]*)\.\R(\d+\sbytes.*?icmp_seq=\d+\h+ttl=\d+\h+time=\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+ms(?:\R\d+\sbytes.*?icmp_seq=\d+\h+ttl=\d+\h+time=\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+ms)*)\R+---.*\R(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted.*?(\d+)\sreceived,\h*(\d+%)\spacket\sloss,\h+time\s(\d+ms)\R.*=\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\sms
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gt9KzY/1).